# Limit the size of log file in php-wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my application php errors and warnings are logged to `error_log` file in present directory.

But the size of the log file become huge(eg: 2Gb,5GB etc)

How can i limit the size of log file in php,wordpress?

Comment: Why not just output the errors in HTML in the browser and skip logging. Anything producing this amount of errors should not be on a public server anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add in wp-config.php file this line`@ini_set( 'log_errors_max_len', '1024' );`.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#configure-error-logging

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But i need logs, don't wish to 'off'. Is there any possible method to restrict the log file size?

Comment: is there any way to fix the size of a file in linux? means linux commands to create files with fixed size.